# make STDOUT_FILENO a new file handler

Tags: linux, dup

I'm confused about executing a file with "> /home/hel/myfile".Is this toally equivalent to dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO) if fd is the file hander of "/home/hel/myfile"? As for kernel, do they work in the same way?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd;

    fd = open("/home/hel/myfile", O_RDWR);  // open a file
    if (fd < 0) {
        printf("open error\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO); /*Is this toally equivalent to shell command  
                              * " > /home/hu /myfile "?
                              */
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they're equivalent. When you run a command with output redirection, the shell executes something similar to your code right before it calls `execlp()` to execute your program.